# Cannot Initialize repo to download Android Source -- No Error Messages?

Tags: android, git, repository

Following directions [here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), I am trying to get source code for the latest version of Android 2.1.  I understand that is android-2.1_r2.1p2.

When I get to the step where I issue the command:

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.1_r2.1p2

I do not get a prompt asking me for my name and email.  The system returns to the prompt with no error message and nothing is downloaded.

I am on an Ubuntu VM with Git Core and Python 2.6 installed on a Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

A very helpful user on IRC channel #android-dev, helped me figure out the problem.  Evidently this happens when you use a proxy.  I use a VPN; so, I shut it off and restarted the virtual manchine and voila the problem was gone.